# CSV upload into BigQuery partitioned table using a string field as partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to upload csv file into bigquery table. My question is if "datestamp_column" is STRING how I can use it as partition field?

An example value from "datestamp_column":  2022-11-25T12:56:48.926500Z

```
def upload_to_bq():

client = bigquery.Client())

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema = client.schema_from_json("schemaa.json"),

    skip_leading_rows=1,
    time_partitioning=bigquery.TimePartitioning(
        type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
        field="datestamp_column",
        expiration_ms=7776000000,  # 90 days.
    ),
)
```

This is failing as it is complaining datestamp_column is STRING and should be TIMESTAMP, DATE or DATETIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able using the partition on the `datestamp_column` field, you have to use `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

The format you indicated for this field corresponds to a timestamp : `datestamp_column: 2022-11-25T12:56:48.926500Z`

In your `BigQuery` schema, you have to change the column type from `STRING` to `TIMESTAMP` for `datestamp_column` field.

Then your ingestion should work correctly because the timestamp format `2022-11-25T12:56:48.926500Z` should be ingested as `TIMESTAMP` in `BigQuery`.

```
input -> STRING with value 2022-11-25T12:56:48.926500Z
result column in BigQuery is TIMESTAMP
```